# Upload multiple videos and images on a Server with apache cordova

Tags: javascript, php, phonegap, apache-cordova

I'm developing a hybrid application using the Apache cordova plug-ins, I can upload images and videos on a server one by one with the file transfer plug-in, but I can not send more images and videos at the same time. this problem? I was thinking of converting images and videos to base64 and then sending the base64 strings corresponding to the server, but I can not find a function that converts the base64 video after it has been acquired.

Comment: `base64_decode()` is probably what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I was looking for, the problem is sending more images and videos simultaneously to a server. To solve this I thought to convert images and videos in base64 and after sending the basic64 strings corresponding to the server, for the images there is no problem thanks to the apache cordova camera plug-in, while I find nothing for the videos.